# Pandas aggregate specific column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

How can I aggregate only specific columns in pandas?

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                    'B': [1, 2, 3, 4],
               'C': np.random.randn(4)})

df.groupby('A').agg(['max']) #works as expected, but gives values for col B & C

df.groupby('A').agg({'Bmax':'B'.max}) #FAILS
```

Comment: What is it you want?

Comment: `df.groupby('A').B.max()`

Comment: `df.groupby('A').agg({'B':'max'}) ` pass to a dict

Answer (score 0):

The .agg call takes a dictionary with the Column Name and the aggregation(s) that you want to apply.  You can apply multiple aggregations (see the example) by passing them as a list.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                    'B': [1, 2, 3, 4],
               'C': np.random.randn(4)})

df.groupby('A').agg(['max']) #works as expected, but gives values for col B & C

df.groupby('A').agg({'B': np.max}) #this will give you the max value for B within each grouping of A
df.groupby('A').agg({'B': [np.max, np.min]})  # you can also use mulitple aggregations (and it automatically adds column names)
```